# Let A be an n by n matrix with the property that $A^TA = AA^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification

Show that $\left\Vert A^Tx \right\Vert = \left\Vert Ax \right\Vert$ for $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

So this is what I did. I need someone to check my work.

1) I squared the left hand side of the equation

$$\left\Vert A^Tx \right\Vert^2$$

2) I then applied the rule $\left\Vert x \right\Vert^2 = \left<x,x\right>$

$$\left<A^Tx,A^Tx\right>$$

3) Since this is just the dot product, I removed the brackets

$$A^Tx \cdot A^Tx$$

4) I took the transpose

$$(A^Tx \cdot  A^Tx)^T = Ax \cdot  Ax$$

5) I then placed the brackets since the inner product is just the dot product

$$\left<Ax ,  Ax\right>$$

6) I then used the rule $\left\Vert x \right\Vert^2 = \left<x,x\right>$ again

$$\left\Vert Ax \right\Vert^2$$

7) I took the square root

$$\left\Vert Ax \right\Vert$$

Is this the correct way to prove that $\left\Vert A^Tx \right\Vert = \left\Vert Ax \right\Vert$?

Comment: If you want a dot product you should use \cdot instead of * for the multiplication.

Comment: What's your justification for step 4? Here's a hint: Use the fact that $\langle x, y \rangle = x^{T}y$.

Comment: Step 4 is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\Vert A^Tx \Vert^2 = \langle A^T x, A^T x \rangle = \langle x, (A^T)^T A^T x \rangle = \langle x, AA^T x \rangle$
$= \langle x, A^T Ax \rangle = \langle (A^T)^T x, Ax \rangle = \langle Ax, Ax \rangle = \Vert Ax \Vert^2, \tag 1$

whence

$\Vert A^T x \Vert = \Vert Ax \Vert. \tag 2$

Answer (score 1):

Step 4 fails because the rule is $(AB)^T=B^TA^T$.  Presumably $x$ is a column vector, and so is $A^Tx$.  The transpose of this has to be a row vector, which is $x^TA$.  You now have $||A^Tx||=||xA||$ which is not what you wanted.